# Why does the value assigned by get<>() in my code change outside the construct?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, auto

Why is the output of statement `2` different from that of statement `1`?

```
// a is of type vector < tuple <int, int> >

for (auto i: a)
{
    get<0>(i)+=get<1>(i);                                       
    cout << get<0>(i) << " " << get<1>(i) << endl;              // 1
}

for (auto i: a) cout << get<0>(i) << " " << get<1>(i) << endl;  // 2
```

Suppose that initially, `a` contains `[7, 3] , [9, 1]`

Then `1` outputs

```
10 3
10 1
```

whereas `2` outputs

```
7 3
9 1
```

In short, the loop enclosing statement `1` seems to have no effect.

I think it has something to do with my usage of `auto` and not using `*i` to change the value, but I don't think that we can use `*i` in `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you do:

```
for (auto i: a)
```

you're making *copies* of every element in `a`. You're iterating by value and modifying local copies of the elements of the container. If you want to actually modify elements of the container, you have to iterate by reference:

```
for (auto& i : a)
        ^^^
```

`auto` does not deduce reference.

Comment: I thought we only needed to worry about pass by reference or pass by value in function arguments. Could you please explain how `auto` is similar to that?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Well, you want to iterate over the objects in `a`, not copies of the objects in `a`. So you need references. `auto` won't deduce a reference - you have to tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your suspicion is correct, in `for (auto i: a)` the `i` contains a copy of the tuple. Any changes affects the copy only.

You can use `for (auto& i: a)` to make changes that affects the "original" tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It slipped my mind. I was trying `*i` instead of doing what you suggested.